# Building an environmental computable general equilibrium for a developping country

Tags: macroeconomics, general-equilibrium, environmental-economics, social-welfare, resource-economics

I managed to get help from this website in 2014 for my masters thesis, and now I'm back with more questions.

I'm a PhD student and the issue at hand concerns environmental economics and the costs of inaction due to environmental problems.
The environmental issues in my country (developping/middle income) are mainly related to:
**1.** water resources depletion (competing usages between drinking water and agricultural use)
**2.** Coal/fossil fuels to generate electricity and transport.

What I want to do is :
**1.** Estimate these environmental issues costs
**2.** Suggest solutions
**3.** Estimate the benefits of said solutions.

I'm doing this for the whole country, not just a small region or location. It's a **macroeconomic analysis**, hence why I think the computable general equilibrium is suitable.

I spent the last 3 months studying these models, how to prepare the data base (SAM), how to code on GAMS, etc. But here is the issues at hand:
**1.** I need a detailed model showing the agents behaviour in details. Because the books I consulted don't go in detail. The articles that I consulted don't show any models at all, they just go straight to the results without even showing the equations, how to derive the solutions, etc.
**2.** I think the modelling bit is what's bugging me, so I'd appreciate if I could get some suggestions about books/tutorials to build a model and do simulations.

If you also have suggestions other than the computable general equilibrium framework, I'm all ears.
Thank you